# Пунктуация последовательности цитат

Tags: пунктуация, цитирование

Добрый день. Каким образом можно осовременить вот этот фрагмент?

> И потом сказать, что изволите, государь батюшко; или государоня матушка. Или что мне прикажете государь; а не так: что, чего, што, как ты говоришь, чего хочешь.

Вопрос в основном о пунктуации. Быть может так?

> И потом сказать: «Что изволите, государь батюшка?», или «государыня матушка». Или: «Что мне прикажите, государь», а не так: «Что?», «чего?», «как ты говоришь?», «чего хочешь?»

Это учебное задание, одно из требований — максимальное соответствие тексту оригинала. Т.е. изменение структуры предложения категорически не приветствуется.

Comment: ...И все пропустили "што?", а его надобно сохранить. Может, первое "что" - питерское, чёткое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы принял Ваш вариант с небольшими изменениями: все вопросительные предложения (восклицания) начинать с большой буквы и еще один знак вопроса добавить (после "государь").

**И потом сказать: «Что изволите, государь батюшка?», или «государыня матушка». Или: «Что мне прикажeте, государь?», а не так: «Что?», «Чего?», «Как ты говоришь?», «Чего хочешь?»**

Answer (score 2):

Согласна с М_Г с небольшими изменениями:

И потом сказать: «Что изволите, государь-батюшка?( или «государыня-матушка»)». Или: «Что мне прикаж**е**те, государь?», а не так: «Что?», «Чего?», «Как ты говоришь?», «Чего хочешь?»

Несколько цитат оформлено в виде прямой речи. В первом предложении к полной фразе есть дополнение, вариант обращения, его лучше взять в скобки как вставную конструкцию.Во втором всё-таки идёт речь об отдельных репликах, а не одной фразе, их лучше перечислить через запятую.

Comment: "Прикажете" - недоглядел (увы), скобки - замечательно. Но  кавычки в кавычках? Внешние кавычки - прямая речь, а это значит, что  герой должен произнести все подряд, включая текст в скобках. А это неверно. Не так ли?

Comment: Может так:  «Что изволите, государь батюшка?» (или "государыня матушка")

Comment: Да, так будет лучше.

Comment: А впрочем, вставная конструкция-то относится к прямой речи, наверное, так:«Что изволите, государь-батюшка( или «государыня-матушка»)?»

Answer (score 0):

**В качестве варианта:**

И потом сказать: «Что изволите, государь батюшка; или государыня матушка?»
 Или: «Что мне прикажите, государь?», а не так: "Что? чего? как ты говоришь? чего хочешь"?

**Пояснение (о вопросительном знаке)**

Розенталь [§ 2. Вопросительный знак](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)

Вопросительный знак может ставиться в вопросительном предложении после **каждого однородного члена с целью расчленения вопроса**: Что я — попугай? индейка? (М.); Кравцов ласково улыбался — его нетерпению? самомнению? гениальности? (Гран.)